# How do I change this parametric equation: $x=t+1/t, y=t^2 + 1/t^2$ into a Cartesian equation?

Tags: parametric, curves

I've just started parametric equations on my own & I am a bit confused on how to convert this parametric equation into a Cartesian equation.

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
x=t + \frac{1}{t}, 
y= t^{2} + \frac{1}{t^{2}}
\end{array}\qquad$$

Comment: Add and subtract 2,  $y = \left(t+\frac1t\right)^2 - 2$.

Comment: @IshaanSingh Please write those comments that answer a question as answer unless you think that the OP might have had something non-trivial to ask but turned out to be trivial because of a typo or other reasons why you think a comment is better than an answer. Here, I don't see any such--please correct me if I am wrong. Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: compute $x^2$ and subtract $y$

Answer (score 2):

$$x=t+1/t$$

$$x^2=(t+1/t)^2$$

Expanding the perfect square $a^2+2ab+b^2$:
$$x^2=t^2+1/t^2+2$$

As $y=t^2+1/t^2$, therefore $y=x^2-2$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Please, however, [use MathJax/latex next time](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score -2):

$$\begin{align}
x&=t+1/t\\        
xt-t&=1 \\    
   t(x-1)&=1\\
 \\                     
t&=1/(x-1)\\
 \\   
y&=t^2+1/t^2\\
\\
y&=1/(x-1)^2 + (x-1)^2
\end{align}$$

Comment: Your solution is not correct:  the very first step is wrong.  If $x = t + 1/t$, then multiplying both sides by $t$ gives $xt = {\color{red}{t^2}} + 1$, not $xt = t+1$.