# How do I change parametric in t to cartesian when I can't re-arrage for t

Tags: parametric

I'm stuck looking at this parametric equation which I have to put in cartesian form

$x=t^2+ \frac1t$,           $y=t^2-\frac 1t$

Something to do with difference of two squares?  I can't see how to eliminate $t$

$xy=t^4-\frac{1}{t^2}$ doesn't help.

I found something similar but couldn't apply it (as far as I could see) to this problem:

[How do I change this parametric equation: $x=t+1/t, y=t^2 + 1/t^2$ into a Cartesian equation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/132051/how-do-i-change-this-parametric-equation-x-t1-t-y-t2-1-t2-into-a-cartesia)

Thanks in advance!
Rob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** $x-y=\frac{2}{t}$ hence $t=\frac{2}{x-y}$.